# Filtering a slice of structs based on a different slice in Golang

Tags: go

In the example code below, I have a few users in `manySimpleUsers` that I would like to remove from `manyFullUsers` based on the Username.

If I do it with a nested couple of `for... range` loops, there will be many cycles required to filter all of the elements, especially when there are large numbers of elements in both Slices.

What is the best way to achieve this in Go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    type FullUser struct {
        UserName  string
        UserEmail string
    }

    manyFullUsers := []FullUser{{"foo", "foo@jawohl.com"},
        {"bar", "bar@jawohl.com"},
        {"baz", "baz@jawohl.com"}}

    type SimpleUser struct {
        UserName string
    }

    manySimpleUsers := []SimpleUser{{"foo"}, {"bar"}}

    fmt.Println(manyFullUsers)
    fmt.Println(manySimpleUsers)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a map then use it to filter.

```
func filterByUserName(fu []FullUser, su []SimpleUser) (out []FullUser) {
    f := make(map[string]struct{}, len(su))
    for _, u := range su {
        f[u.UserName] = struct{}{}
    }
    for _, u := range fu {
        if _, ok := f[u.UserName]; ok {
            out = append(out, u)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/zSXq91WzE6)

Comment: By the way, you can save some bytes using map of bools:

```
    f := make(map[string]bool, len(su))
    // Later, inside loop:
    f[u.UserName] = true
```

Comment: @coquin `struct{}` uses 0 bytes, where bools uses at least 1.

Comment: Thanks! I could directly unmarshal into a `map[string]struct{}` because the "filtering" JSON's format is in my control.  I also needed to do the *reverse* of what you had written, so I just used `!ok` and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you can use Filter() and Exist() from https://github.com/ledongthuc/goterators that I created to reuse aggregate & transform functions.

[image]

```golang
    filteredFullUsers := goterators.Filter(manyFullUsers, func(item FullUser) bool {
        return !goterators.Exist(manySimpleUsers, SimpleUser{item.UserName})
    })
```

You also can build a map from manySimpleUsers that will be helpful to optimize searching username.

This lib requires the Go 1.18 to use that support generic + dynamic type you want to use with.